# OnTouch and OnLongPress work together

Tags: android, ontouchlistener, onlongclicklistener

I impleme

```
public class TextViewer extends Activity implements OnTouchListener
```

and

```
tv.setOnLongClickListener(itemLongClickHandler);
tv.setOnTouchListener(this);
```

But I only the second one works.

Can I have them both work?

Comment: What is `itemLongClickHandler`? Can you show the source code of the `itemLongClickHandler = ` section?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you always returning true from onTouch()? You should return false if you want normal event processing to happen.

There may be a better approach than this - what types of event are you looking to handle in onTouch()?

Best wishes,

Phil Lello